# Instruct Scrapy to ignore the content length of a site

Tags: python, http, curl, scrapy

**Question**

How can I ignore the content length of a response in Scrapy?

**Explanation**

Consider this curl command"

`curl -u <user:pass> http://data.icecat.biz/export/level4/NL/files.index.xml`

It currently fails because the content-length header has been set incorrectly by Icecat.

We can fix this by ignoring the content-length by using the *ignore-content-length* parameter of curl:

`curl --ignore-content-length -u <user:pass>  http://data.icecat.biz/export/level4/NL/files.index.xml`

And everything works fine!

However I have no clue how to do this in [Scrapy](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search.html?q=content%20length&check_keywords=yes&area=default#).
Google and the documentation reveals nothing to me.

Before I dig into the Scrapy code to fix this, perhaps somebody already did this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is fixed in Scrapy 1.5
New setting is introduced - DOWNLOAD_FAIL_ON_DATALOSS
You need to set it to False in your project settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the maximum response size that Scrapy will download to 'unlimited' using `download_maxsize=0` at the command line (using `scrapy crawl myspider -s download_maxsize=0`). The default is 1024 bytes.

You can also do this per-spider in their `scrapy.spiders.Spider.custom_settings` attribute, per-project in the `myproject.settings` module of a Scrapy project, or globally within the `scrapy.settings.default_settings` module.

See the official Scrapy documentation for this option [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:reqmeta-download_maxsize) or further instructions on built-in settings [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html).

Comment: The size is not the issue. This setting ignores the size as you suggested: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-maxsize However the size is not the problem. It is the size exceeding the reported size. However I tried as you suggested. Error stays the same, which is:   `Chunked decoder in 'CHUNK_LENGTH' state, still expecting more data to get to 'FINISHED`

Comment: Looks like that's a problem with the [Twisted framework](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/efab88424ddde53433fcc2422d36bf61046bb373/twisted/web/http.py#L1664). I don't have access to play with IceCat's data to test the chunked-encoded response but [this issue](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6148) was reported to Twisted a few years ago and it may be relevant if it was never closed. I'll poke around a bit.